# How to manage selected post-formats in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, post, custom-post-type

```
 'supports' => array('title','author','post-formats'),
```

Now display all types of post-formats but i want to display only selected.

**like : link,audio,video**

I wants to something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'link', 'audio', 'video' ) );
```

By default it adds all of the registered formats, but like this, you can choose which to add

You can read about the different formats, and how to add them, in the codex : [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats)

EDIT :

If you are working with a child theme, and never want to use the other formats, you can call this :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'childtheme_formats', 11 );
function childtheme_formats(){
     add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery', 'link' ) );
}
```

EDIT :

According to the comment, you only want this on a single post type :

Then you can do like this :

```
<?php add_post_type_support( $post_type, $supports ) ?>
```

Where `$support` can be a string or an array : so in your task :

So you might be able to do something like this:

```
function test_add_formats_support_for_cpt() {
    add_post_type_support( 'yourCustomPostType', 'post-formats', array('link', 'audio', 'video') );
}
add_action( 'init', 'test_add_formats_support_for_cpt' );
```

This is untested, so I am not sure if it works - let me know

Comment: selected post-formats in custom post type only.
If we can add like this removed from post also. One more can we add own options also?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit or manage the custom post type formats by overwriting the default post formats.

create a function that will return an array of the post formats that our post type supports like audio, gallery, image, and video.

```
function customposttype_allowed_formats() {

return array( 'audio', 'gallery', 'image', 'video' );
}
```

We will use "theme support" system and change the theme-supported format and will limit to our post types dashboard screens so that it won’t mess with other post types

```
add_action( 'load-post.php',     'support_customposttype_filter' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'support_customposttype_filter' );
add_action( 'load-edit.php',     'support_customposttype_filter' );

function support_customposttype_filter() {

$screen = get_current_screen();

// Return if not customposttype screen.
if ( empty( $screen->post_type ) ||  $screen->post_type !== 'custom_post_type' )
    return;

// Check theme supports formats.
if ( current_theme_supports( 'post-formats' ) ) {

    $formats = get_theme_support( 'post-formats' );

    // If we have formats, add theme support for only the allowed formats.
    if ( isset( $formats[0] ) ) {
        $new_formats = array_intersect( $formats[0], customposttype_allowed_formats() );

        // Remove post formats support.
        remove_theme_support( 'post-formats' );

        // If the theme supports the allowed formats, add support for them.
        if ( $new_formats )
            add_theme_support( 'post-formats', $new_formats );
    }
}

// Filter the default post format.
add_filter( 'option_default_post_format', 'customposttype_format_filter', 95 );
 }
```

There is a filter on the default post format at the end here we can overwrite the default post formats if it's not one of the approved formats (audio, gallery, image, and video).

```
function customposttype_format_filter( $format ) {

return in_array( $format, customposttype_allowed_formats() ) ? $format : 'standard';
}
```